# win32 CreateProcess cannot convert parameter 2 from 'char *__w64 ' to 'LPWSTR' error

Tags: c++, winapi, unicode

hello all
i have code from open source project that im integrating into my code . 
now my code settings in visual studio 2008 character set is Unicode . and the external code is 
Multi-Byte Character Set.   when i change the character setting in my application after adding the new source 
im getting other errors in my code .
so reading from the net i guess i need to make some changes to the external code to support unicode. 
here is my code :

```
string FullPathToExe = c:\\foo\\boo.exe;
vector<char> str2(FullPathToExe.begin(), FullPathToExe.end());
    str2.push_back('\0');
    if (!CreateProcess(NULL,
                     &str2[0],
                    NULL,
                    NULL,
                    TRUE,
                    0,
                    NULL,
                    NULL,
                    &si,
                    &pi))
and the error is :
 : error C2664: 'CreateProcessW' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'char *__w64 ' 
 to 'LPWSTR'
```

im not win32 programmer and this is new to me.

how can i support both developer that are using multi byte and Unicode ?

Thanks for helping

Comment: Where does pszAPI come from? Removing this from the question so you can repost it as a new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first one use `vector<wchar_t>` instead of `vector<char>`.
For the second one use `L"ERROR: API    = %s.\n   error code = %d.\n   message    = %s.\n"` instead of `"ERROR: API    = %s.\n   error code = %d.\n   message    = %s.\n"` (note the `L` at the start.

Comment: the first problem was fixed , but the second still gives me the error:error C2664: 'wsprintfW' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'CHAR [512]' to 'LPWSTR' , its the CHAR szPrintBuffer[512]; that is the problematic one

Comment: Use `wchar_t szPrintBuffer[512]` instead then.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `std::wstring` and `vector<wchar_t>` and prefix your strings and chars with L.

Answer (score 1):

Do this instead:

```
wstring FullPathToExe = "c:\\foo\\boo.exe";
    if (!CreateProcess(NULL,
                     FullPathToExe.c_str(),
                    NULL,
                    NULL,
                    TRUE,
                    0,
                    NULL,
                    NULL,
                    &si,
                    &pi))
```

Comment: @Dani, it is if `FullPathToExe` is a `wstring`.

Answer (score 0):

a) you may undefine UNICODE macro in your project settings

b) You may use ascii versions of functions you called, replace wsprintf with sprintf and CreateProcess with CreateProcessA